# Как сделать переход по ссылки при нажатии на пункт меню?

Tags: html, css, веб-сайт, tilda

Делается сайт на платформе Tilda. Имеется стандартное меню с выпадающим второго уровня.
Не приложу ума как сделать так, что бы при наведении на основной пункт меню открывалось меню второго уровня, а при нажатии - переходить на основную страницу раздела.

Comment: <script> $("[href='#submenu:more']").click(function() { document.location = "/page-to-link"; }); </script>

Answer (score 0):

Берем открываем документацию Тильды и видим два варианта решения

**Вариант 1. Использование встроенных элементов**

Под списком пунктов меню нажмите на кнопку «Добавить пункты второго уровня» — напротив пунктов меню появятся иконки в виде знака «+».
Нажмите на «+» для добавления пункта подменю
Укажите название пункта и ссылку

**Вариант 2. Использование блока ME601**

Блок ME601 позволяет добавить подразделы к пунктам основного меню. Как это работает:

Добавьте на страницу блок ME601
В блоке МЕ601 пропишите ссылку вида #submenu:more
В основном меню в поле ссылка, напротив пункта, к которому вы хотите сделать подразделы, укажите #submenu:more.
Примечание: "#submenu:more" может быть любым словом, например: #submenu:portfolio или #submenu:aboutus

Пункты меню второго уровня будут показываться при наведении в формате выпадающего меню. В мобильных версиях меню будет открываться по тапу.

Сам пункт основного меню кликабельным не будет. Если нужно чтобы на нем была ссылка, продублируете этот пункт в выпадающем меню.

Comment: У меня добавлены подпункты в разделе "Контент" у блока меню, но тогда пропадает возможность оставить ссылку для родительского пункта меню. В этом то и интерес, добавить клик по основному пункту!)